# Bootstrap navbar item active depending on filename?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently building my website using the bootstrap framework, I'm having a small issue in that for the menu item I'd like to be active depending on the filename using an if statement.

For example, if filename is "about" the "about" tab would be active.

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
</li>



var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert(filename);
```

If anyone is able to offer assistance I'd really appreciate it, I've been working on this for the past 3 hours without any success.

Comment: I would suggest you researching how <a> tags work, it sounds like it will solve your problem. https://html.com/tags/a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already sucessfully retrieving the filename from the URL. With that you can use a jQuery selector to add the *active* class to the corresponding link.

Assumption: You are using jQuery as it's currently an requirement for Bootstrap components.

Example:

```
<script>
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);    

$('a[href*="' + filename + '"]').addClass('active');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've been trying to get your suggestion to work, but I haven't been successful, if you have a minute spare could you have a quick check on pastebin please, https://pastebin.com/KA33TkeJ

Comment: just to clarify, the above source is on a file called about.html

Comment: @coding_with_tea two issues: 1) Line25 for this solution the filename needs to appear in the href attribute of the a tag. 2) Your script needs to be put after you load jQuery. See this corrected pastebin (save it as about.html) for comparison. https://pastebin.com/4nvNsXDc

Comment: Thank you so much! that's perfect, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can check all the nav bar menus to find the match.
Here is an example

```
$('.navbar ul li a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // if the current path is like this link, make it active
    if($this.attr('href').indexOf(filename) !== -1){
        $this.parents('li').addClass('active');
        return false;
    }
})
```

Where "filename" is your actual current file name.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.nav-link').removeClass("active");
$('#' + filename).addClass("active");
```

use this code inside the script tag and please make sure you add the id to each li equivalent to filename.

Let me know if you face any another issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've tried your example but it doesn't seem to be working for me, I've posted the code on pastebin if you could have a quick look for me please, thank you https://pastebin.com/Uv4jqNYd

Answer (score 0):

As per your html code, you need to add `active` class to [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) of `a` tag. So try this code

```
$('.nav-item').removeClass('active'); //Remove active class from elements
$('a[href*="' + filename + '"]').parent().addClass("active"); // add active class
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a dynamic way with a native javascript

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var file = filename.split(".");
var TagItems = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
for(navitem of TagItems)
    {
        for(item of navitem.children)
            {
              var targetFile = item.getAttribute("href").split(".");
                if(targetFile[0] == file[0])
                    navitem.classList.add("active");
                else
                    navitem.classList.remove("active");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but it doesn't seem to work, https://pastebin.com/Qk6b95hZ if you could have a quick look I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: i think it's not working because you are using php .. you can check it in my codepen 
https://codepen.io/aziada/pen/BEgaEV